# How to make the processing of multiple variables more compact in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make some practice code.

Is there a way to make the print code more pleasing to the eye?

```
#Assigns a, b, c to var 1, 2, 3
global a, b, c
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3


def myfunc():
  print("") #Adds a space to look more aesthetic
  print("a = " + str(a) )#prints variable as string
  print("b = " + str(b) )#^
  print("c = " + str(c) )#^

myfunc()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary to represent your data:

```
data = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

def myfunc(d):
    print("")
    for k,v in d.items():
        print(f"{k} = {v}")

myfunc(data)
```

Comment: Can you give me some insight on how this works? Why did you use k and v?

Comment: d.items() give you an iterator of the items in the dictionary.  The for loop goes through the iterator item by item.  Each item consists of a key, and a value.  You can call these whatever you want, but i usually use k for key and v for value.